# Create table with firedac without SQL Script

Tags: database, delphi, design-patterns, firedac

Firedac library centralizes database behavior and have a lot of methods which works fine without care about the Database Type. Actually, using native drivers for most common databases, Firedac hides subtle differences on syntax allowing very flexible changes of database platform.
For example, generators and autoinc fields are easily detectable, CAST and parameters works fine allowing easy migration between databases.

**How to use Firedac power to create New Table without instantiate FDQuery, which runs a SQL Script `CREATE TABLE`?**

I hope to create any Object and, calling specific FieldByName for each Object Field, record it on database, but first I need to certify:

1. If Table is already created
2. If Field is already created
3. If record is already created

This is the code I have, so far:

```
TRecCustomer = record
  Id:integer;
  Name:String;
  Birthday:TDate;
end;

ICustomer = interface
  procedure setCustomerId(Value: Integer);
  procedure setCustomerName(Value: String);
  procedure SetBirthday(Value: TDate);
  procedure Post;
end;

TCustomer = class(TInterfacedObjet, ICustomer)
  CustomerObject=TRecCustomer;

  procedure setCustomerId(Value: Integer);
  procedure setCustomerName(Value: String);
  procedure SetBirthday(Value: TDate);
  procedure Post;
end;

procedure TCustomer.Post;
begin
  if not TableExists('Customer') then CreateTable('Customer');
  if not FieldExists('Name') then CreateField('Customer','name',ftString,[],40);
  if not FieldExists('Id') then CreateField('Customer','Id',ftInteger,[cAutoInc,cNotNull]);
  if not FieldExists('Birthday') then CreateField('Customer','birthday',ftDate);
end;
```

Imagine the procedures

```
CreateTable(Tablename: String)
CreateField(FieldName: String; FieldType: TDataType; Constraints: TConstraints; Length: Integer = 0);
```

where

```
TConstraints = set of (cAutoInc, cNotNull, cUnique, cEtc);
```

I can do it for specific database, for example Sqlite or Firebird, but I don't know hou to do for any database using Firedac resources.

---

I found `FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDTable.CreateTable(ARecreate: Boolean = True;  AParts: TFDPhysCreateTableParts = [tpTable .. tpIndexes])`, suggested by @Ondrej Kelle but I don't understood `AParts` usage. Somebody have an example? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDTable.CreateTable

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try [`TFDTable.CreateTable`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDTable.CreateTable)

Comment: thanks @OndrejKelle, I edited the question with your recomendation but I yet need an example to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a [**TFDTable**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDTable) object, describe your table at least by specifying [**TableName**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDTable.TableName) and adding field definitions in the [**FieldDefs**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.FieldDefs) collection. In practice you'll usually create also a primary key index for some field (that's what can be done by the [**AddIndex**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.AddIndex) method). After you describe your table, call [**CreateTable**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDTable.CreateTable) method. A minimal example can be:

```
var
  Table: TFDTable;
begin
  Table := TFDTable.Create(nil);
  try
    Table.Connection := FDConnection1;
    { specify table name }
    Table.TableName := 'MyTable';
    { add some fields }
    Table.FieldDefs.Add('ID', ftInteger, 0, False);
    Table.FieldDefs.Add('Name', ftString, 50, False);
    { define primary key index }
    Table.AddIndex('pkMyTableID', 'ID', '', [soPrimary]);
    { and create it; when the first parameter is True, an existing one is dropped }
    Table.CreateTable(False);
  finally
    Table.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If you want to use the [SQLite ROWID feature](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) (ID column INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is also the row identifier and thus will be generated automatically), change the type of field ID from ftInteger to ftAutoIncrement, and the Required parameter to true, i.e. `Table.FieldDefs.Add('ID', ftAutoIncrement, 0, True);` . FireDAC knows what to do. The convention then is also to call the field ROWID. If fact, in tests, this seems to work (with FireDAC) even without creating the index.